# Aavance custom field can't hide my page content editor

Tags: wordpress, editor, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using ACF version 5.9.1 on Wordpress 5.5.1.
I can't hide my content editor.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you already tried to hide as per ACF documentation.
[image]

If you using Gutenberg as I understand You cannot hide the new editor https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/remove-gutenberg-block-editor-with-hide-on-screen/

Comment: What do you mean by default? If you on Wordpress 5.5.1 so you using Gutenberg?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for Gutenberg blocks if you install old editor.

So,

1. Install plugin Classic Editor
2. Activate it
3. Go to your Field group
4. Set Hide on screen option for Content Editor

Now you will see only your custom fields.